# Find index of consecutive values within a dataframe when number of consecutive values is below a certain threshold

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
                     night  DSWRF_integ
ForecastTime
2018-05-12 00:00:00    1.0            1
2018-05-12 00:15:00    0.0            1
2018-05-12 00:30:00    0.0            1
2018-05-12 00:45:00    0.0            1
2018-05-12 01:00:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 01:15:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 01:30:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 01:45:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 02:00:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 02:15:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 02:30:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 02:45:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 03:00:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 03:15:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 03:30:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 03:45:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 04:00:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 04:15:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 04:30:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 04:45:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 05:00:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 05:15:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 05:30:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 05:45:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 06:00:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 06:15:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 06:30:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 06:45:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 07:00:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 07:15:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 07:30:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 07:45:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 08:00:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 08:15:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 08:30:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 08:45:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 09:00:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 09:15:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 09:30:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 09:45:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 10:00:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 10:15:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 10:30:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 10:45:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 11:00:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 11:15:00    0.0            1
2018-05-12 11:30:00    0.0            1
2018-05-12 11:45:00    0.0            1

2018-05-12 12:00:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 12:15:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 12:30:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 12:45:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 13:00:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 13:15:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 13:30:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 13:45:00    0.0            0

2018-05-12 14:00:00    1.0            1
2018-05-12 14:15:00    1.0            1
2018-05-12 14:30:00    1.0            1
2018-05-12 14:45:00    1.0            1
2018-05-12 15:00:00    1.0            1
```

I am trying to figure out a logic, without iterating over the dataframe as it is too slow, to be able to convert consecutive zeros in the column **DSWRF_integ** to ones, **only when** the number of consecutive zeros is smaller than a specific threshold (for example threshold=10).

In this specific case,  I would like to replace all the zeros in column DSWRF_integ, with ones, for the time period **2018-05-12 12:00:00**  to **2018-05-12 13:45:00** , because the number of consecutive zeros there is smaller than 10.

The resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
                     night  DSWRF_integ
ForecastTime
2018-05-12 00:00:00    1.0            1
2018-05-12 00:15:00    0.0            1
2018-05-12 00:30:00    0.0            1
2018-05-12 00:45:00    0.0            1
2018-05-12 01:00:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 01:15:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 01:30:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 01:45:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 02:00:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 02:15:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 02:30:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 02:45:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 03:00:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 03:15:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 03:30:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 03:45:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 04:00:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 04:15:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 04:30:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 04:45:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 05:00:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 05:15:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 05:30:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 05:45:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 06:00:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 06:15:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 06:30:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 06:45:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 07:00:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 07:15:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 07:30:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 07:45:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 08:00:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 08:15:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 08:30:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 08:45:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 09:00:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 09:15:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 09:30:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 09:45:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 10:00:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 10:15:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 10:30:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 10:45:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 11:00:00    0.0            0
2018-05-12 11:15:00    0.0            1
2018-05-12 11:30:00    0.0            1
2018-05-12 11:45:00    0.0            1

2018-05-12 12:00:00    0.0            1
2018-05-12 12:15:00    0.0            1
2018-05-12 12:30:00    0.0            1
2018-05-12 12:45:00    0.0            1
2018-05-12 13:00:00    0.0            1
2018-05-12 13:15:00    0.0            1
2018-05-12 13:30:00    0.0            1
2018-05-12 13:45:00    0.0            1

2018-05-12 14:00:00    1.0            1
2018-05-12 14:15:00    1.0            1
2018-05-12 14:30:00    1.0            1
2018-05-12 14:45:00    1.0            1
2018-05-12 15:00:00    1.0            1
```

I have tried various approaches, using auxilliary columns but none of them has produced anything close to what I want. Any help would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: Can we know what you're trying so far ? So that we know what is "too slow" for you.

Comment: I have been trying by looping over the dataframe rows, both by using __df.itertuples__ and __df.iterrows__  and various conditional statements, but I am iterating through dataframes that have millions of rows so this approach is too slow. I have not kept any of the minimal examples I made, as I have been trying to achieve what I mention using logical indexing :)

Comment: try [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/20587/find-the-consecutive-zeros-in-a-dataframe-and-do-a-conditional-replacement)

Comment: @Chris You should post this as an answer and link to it.

Comment: @IMCoins I do not really have the time at the moment. Feel free to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
th = 3 # set threshold

# Sets to True rows that are 0
x = df.DSWRF_integ.eq(0)

# Takes the cumulative sum of rows where changes occur (thus where diff != 0)
g = x.astype(int).diff().fillna(0).ne(0).cumsum()

# Groups the original df with g and replaces 0 to 1 where the length of consecutive zeroes
# is smaller than the threshold
ix = x[x].groupby(g[x]).transform('size').lt(th) = 1
df.loc[ix[ix].index, 'DSWRF_integ'] = 1
```

---

**Example**

I've created this sample dataframe to more easily check the resulting dataframe. I've also created a final dataframe with all intermediate `pd.Series` added to it for a better understanding of all steps:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[0,0,0,2,1,3,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,1]})
```

Now, setting for instance a threshold of 4, should turn to `1` all zeroes except those in rows `9` to `12`:

```
result = df.copy()
th = 4
x = df.col1.eq(0)
g = x.astype(int).diff().fillna(0).ne(0).cumsum()
ix = x[x].groupby(g[x]).transform('size').lt(th) 
result.loc[ix[ix].index, 'col1'] = 1

df.assign(x=x, g=g, ix=ix, result=result)

     col1   x    g    ix     result
0      0   True  0   True       1
1      0   True  0   True       1
2      0   True  0   True       1
3      2  False  1    NaN       2
4      1  False  1    NaN       1
5      3  False  1    NaN       3
6      0   True  2   True       1
7      1  False  3    NaN       1
8      2  False  3    NaN       2
9      0   True  4  False       0
10     0   True  4  False       0
11     0   True  4  False       0
12     0   True  4  False       0
13     1  False  5    NaN       1
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer ?

Comment: Yes @IMCoins, on it

Comment: Let me know if this helps @FanisSofianopoulos or of any doubts you have

Comment: @yatu thank you very much for the detailed answer and effort. This is not exactly what I want, but I was in the process of trying to make it work. What I want, is that 0 are converted to 1 only when the number of consecutive 0 is __smaller__ than the specified threshold. What your code does, is that it does the opposite, that is, when the number of consecutive 0 is __higher__ than the threshold :)

Comment: My bad :-) Check now, just a small change

Comment: Well I'll  try and help you with what I can... Perhaps you can adapt it from the example i've shared, where it does work as expected

Comment: @yatu I did a mistake while adapting your example to my case - I corrected that and it now works exactly as it should. Thank you so much. I will now try to understand exactly what it does :D